# How to use a CTE as a loop?

Tags: t-sql, loops, cursor, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Is there any way to convert this cursor into a looping/recursive CTE? I've been reading some of the articles on CTEs but they've been about hierarchies and they made my head spin.

```
create table #things(id int)
insert into #things (id)
values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

create table #items (name varchar(8), id int)
insert into #items
values ('grodd', 1), ('duck', 2), ('time', 3), ('nix', 4), ('quasar', 7)


declare @count int = 0
declare @id int = 0
declare @name varchar(8) = null

-- load cursor with ids from table #things
declare test_cursor cursor for
select id
from #things

-- get id first row and set @id with id
open test_cursor
fetch next from test_cursor into @id

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @count = (select count(id) from #items where id = @id)
    if (@count > 0) 
    begin
        set @name = (select top 1 name from #items where id = @id)
        exec dbo.test_stored_procedure @name
    end
    -- get id from next row and set @id = id
    fetch next from test_cursor into @id
end 

close test_cursor
deallocate test_cursor

drop table #items
drop table #things
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a function instead of the procedure then there is no need to use CTE. You can use function directly in select clause or do something else like this

```
select result.*
from #items as i
inner join #things as t on t.id = i.id
cross apply 
dbo.test_stored_function (i.name) as result
```

Or if you absolutely want to use CTE then you can use this code

```
with some_array as (
    select i.name
    from #items as i
    inner join #things as t on t.id = i.id
)
select result.* from some_array as sa
cross apply
dbo.test_stored_function (sa.name) as result
```

In this case the `dbo.test_stored_function` have to be a table-valued function (not a scalar). In examples above one of the returning column from the function is `nvarchar` named `name` but it can be wathever you need.

If you absolutely have to use a procedure then I can suggest to try with dynamic sql query. You can prepare a single string with multiple queries inside (using a concatenation in other sql query where result contains data for procedure parameters) and execute it with function `sp_executesql` like in this example

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'execute dbo.some_procedure val1; execute dbo.some_procedure val2;';
execute sp_executesql @sql;
```

You can read more about function `sp_executesql` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188001%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396